# Center aligning buttons inside div dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which can have 2 or 4 buttons based on different scenario. I want the buttons inside the div to be center aligned. How it can be done. I have submitted my code below.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px;">
    <input type="submit" style="float:left;"  value="Prev"/><input type="reset"  value="Reset" style="float:left;"/>
   <input type="submit"  value="Submit" style="float:left;"/><input style="float:left;" type="submit"  value="Close"/></div>
```

The problem is it works when four buttons gets displayed but not for 3,2 and 1 button scenario. How to center align this without specifying width ? Plz help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use `text-align: center` on the container element. Also, avoid using *inline* styles...

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px; text-align: center;">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eK22Y/)

> Note: Make sure that you use `text-align: left;` if you have any text
>   inside that `div` else they will be centered as well.

---

As you commented, it looks like center to me

[image]

---

Still you are not believing that they are perfectly centered, I would tweak the containers `width` and will show you that they are centered....

[image]

[image]

**With 2 Buttons**

[image]

[image]

> Note: Make sure you use CSS Reset as well... So that you get
>   consistent styles in all browsers though this should be centered
>   regardless of resetting the styles.

Comment: Actually i got screwed from external CSS affecting my current code. Thanks for your replies. May be thats the reason i think.

Answer (score 4):

If buttons are the only thing present in your div, then you should give **text-align:center** property to the div. With this everything inside the div will be center aligned not depending on the width.

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px;text-align:center;">
<input type="submit" value="Prev"/><input type="reset" value="Reset"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><input type="submit" value="Close"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:100%"><div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
<input type="submit"  value="One"/><input type="reset"  value="Two"/> <input type="submit"  value="Three"/><input type="reset"  value="Four"/></div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eK22Y/10/

Answer (score 1):

Can you use below code and let me know. Just used text align centre

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 656px; text-align:center">
<input type="submit"  value="Prev"/><input type="reset"  value="Reset"/>
```

Comment: The width attribute not allowing it to be exact center in all scenario's.

Comment: To me it looks centre even if i use 1 , 2 or 3 buttons

Comment: Using the text-align:center and adding a background color - seems center to me: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/eK22Y/2/

Comment: For the four button scenario it will be center if the button is reduced to 2 by a dynamic scenario its not exactly center.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply specify **text-align:center;** style for div.

Here, the code for you reference.

```
Style
---------------------
.row { text-align:center; }
.row input { margin:0px 5px; }


HTML
------------------
<div class="row">
   <input type="submit"  value="Prev"/><input type="reset"  value="Reset"/>
   <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/><input type="submit"  value="Close"/>
</div>
```

any element inside div having class 'row' will be center align.